# Unable to locate an element using appium

Tags: java, testing, appium, element

I was trying to select a particular element in my mobile app to enter mobile number.in my app i have done all other works..but i can't able to locate my Mobile number field to enter Mobile number. currently it was performing the click operation on to a country code spinner prefix to my mobile number field..

**The input field in my app is given below**

[image]

**The UI automator view is given below**

[image]

The codes i tried are

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Mobile Number']")).sendKeys("8129497946");
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'ext-element-65')']")).sendKeys("8129497946");
```

any solutions?

Comment: Details available in             https://discuss.appium.io/t/cant-able-to-locate-an-element-using-appium/17443/9

Answer (score 0):

`find_element(id: 'ext-element-65').sendKeys("8129497946")`

This is how it is usually written. Please make sure you select `driver.findelement` by  `id`, in case your giving resource-id as locator.

Comment: This one is given  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@text, 'Mobile Number')]")).click();

Comment: If it has any relation between the index number of Spinner and EditText (Both are 1)

Comment: Did you try tapping the element by id? you have got the resource id for this element right?

Comment: Yes i tried this one also    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'ext-element-65')']")).sendKeys("8129497946");

Comment: No dude! Just do with id
` driver.findElement(By.id("ex‌​t-element-65").‌​sendKeys("8129497946‌​");

See if you can find syntax for asserting an element with id in whatever language you are writing. Currently, you are asserting through xpath which is wrong